# Bypassing the IncompleteRead exception

Tags: python, tweepy, urllib3

I am writing a Twitter stream listener in Python3 using Tweepy. I get this error after streaming for a while:

```
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(0 bytes read)', IncompleteRead(0 bytes read))
```

How can I just bypass this, reconnect and keep going?

I have done:

```
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import ReadTimeoutError, IncompleteRead
```

And:

```
while True:
    try:
        twitter_stream.filter(track=keywordlist, follow=userlist)

    except IncompleteRead:
        continue
```

But still getting the error.

Answer (score 6):

The exception you're getting is a `urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError` exception.

Try:

```
from urllib3.exceptions import ProtocolError

while True:
    try:
        twitter_stream.filter(track=keywordlist, follow=userlist)

    except ProtocolError:
        continue
```

Comment: Of course! Thanks! I noticed just when pressing the button to post the question.